# Fluent Assertions PropertyInfo BeDecoratedWith

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

The .NET [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions) library (version 2.1.0) has several `BeDecoratedWith<T>()` implementations for asserting that a type (or type member) has a given attribute applied to it. These calls look like this:

```
typeof(X).Should()
    .BeDecoratedWith<SomeAttribute>(attr => attr.Name == expectedValue);
```

The lambda expression asserts that the attribute has a `Name` equal to some `expectedValue`.

This is great when the `sut` is a type, but when it is a member there is no overload of `BeDecoratedWith<T>` that takes a lambda expression.

```
// compiler error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
typeof(X).GetProperty("xyz").Should()
    .BeDecoratedWith<SomeAttribute>(attr => attr.Name == expectedValue);
```

The documentation quickly covers [extensibility](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki/Documentation#extensibility), but I'm having trouble working out how I'd create an overload (or extension method) of `BeDecoratedWith<T>` on the [`PropertyInfoAssertions`](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/blob/master/FluentAssertions.Net35/Types/PropertyInfoAssertions.cs) class that accepts a lambda like the one above.

Could someone show me the proper way to extent Fluent Assertions to accomplish this?

Comment: So, what are you having trouble with in particular?

Comment: The best way to extend the library. It would see like I could extend `ProprtyInfoAssertions` but then I'd have to re-write all the attribute handling code myself, which seems wrong.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create an extension method on PropertyInfoAssertions that supports the lambda expression and uses the SubjectProperties property to access the actual property.
2. Fork the repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions) and add it directly to the framework. I will accept pull requests.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I'd need to fork the code to do it "properly". Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: No, you don't have to. You can still use option 1. You only need option 2 if you want me to include it in 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is to wait a while and then get the latest version, as this issue seems to have been fixed recently :)

http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/workitem/12455

Comment: This isn't a fix to my problem. I am using that code, but want it to do more.